# speechSynthesis.getVoices (Web Speech API) doesn't show some of the locally installed voices

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

I'm trying to use Web Speech API to read text on my web page. But I found that some of the SAPI5 voices installed in my Windows 10 would not show up in the output of `speechSynthesis.getVoices()`, including the `Microsoft Eva Mobile` on Windows 10 "unlock"ed by importing a registry file. These voices could work fine in local TTS programs like `Balabolka` but they just don't show in the browser. Are there any specific rules by which the browser chooses whether to list the voices or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what was wrong. I was using Microsoft Edge and it seems that Edge only shows some of Microsoft voices. If I use Firefox, the other installed voices will also show up. So it was Edge's fault.